# uinput works only in interactive shell

Tags: python

```
import uinput

device = uinput.Device([uinput.KEY_LEFTCTRL, uinput.KEY_LEFTALT, uinput.KEY_T])

device.emit_combo([uinput.KEY_LEFTCTRL, uinput.KEY_LEFTALT, uinput.KEY_T])
```

The above code works perfectly in python shell but not in a file. What's wrong is this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this myself.
If create new uinput.Device and instanly send input, uinput will not working.
It required some delay.
So, this is my solution:

```
import uinput
device = uinput.Device([uinput.KEY_LEFTCTRL, uinput.KEY_LEFTALT, uinput.KEY_T])
time.sleep(0.1)
device.emit_combo([uinput.KEY_LEFTCTRL, uinput.KEY_LEFTALT, uinput.KEY_T])
```

Comment: you sir saved me ... I should have googled this earlier